# Fullscreen canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have made a Google Bouncing Balls animation with Google scripts, but my canvas isn't fullscreen, I tried all the solution, but they doesn't solved the problem.

Here is my [TEMPLATE](http://codepen.io/EgorGunko/pen/YqmydJ)

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

I tried this:

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }

#myCanvas { display:block; }
```

Sorry for my English, Thanks)

Comment: Don't use CSS to resize your canvas -- that will distort your drawings. Instead set the canvas element's `.width=window.innerWidth` & `.height=window.innerHeight`.

Comment: @markE unfoturnatelly, as You can see nothing changed [TEMPLATE](http://codepen.io/EgorGunko/pen/YqmydJ)